# AWS Glue Crawler creates a table for every file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I created a test Redshift cluster and enabled audit logging on the database. This creates connection logs, user logs and user activity logs (details about the logs are available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/db-auditing.html#db-auditing-logs)). This creates the logs in S3 bucket in the following location:

```
s3://bucket_name/AWSLogs/123456789012/redshift/<region>/<year>/<month>/<date>/*_<log_type>_<timestamp>.gz
```

Next I created a Glue Crawler and pointed the data store to `s3://bucket_name/AWSLogs/123456789012/redshift` and left the remaining options as the default values.

When I run the Crawler, it creates a separate table for every log item. Instead, I expect it to create 3 tables (one each for user log, user activity log and connection log).

Following are some things I tried with no success:

- Updated the data store to point to prefix further inside the bucket like `s3://bucket_name/AWSLogs/123456789012/redshift/<region>`.
- Grouping behavior: create a single schema for each S3 path
- Configuration options: add new columns only

Am I missing something here? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant keep all 3 schema files under one folder. They should be in separate folders before running crawler at root folder

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works. I tried what you mentioned by moving one set of logs (the connection logs) to a different prefix and tried running the crawler by pointing it to the new prefix. AWS Glue created a single table.

Comment: Great! Good to know it. :-)